# How do I print x amount of integers per line in C?

Tags: c, while-loop

How to print the `integers` from 1 to 20 using a while loop and the `counter` variable `x`.

I need to print only five integers per line. [**Hint**: Use the calculation `x % 5`. When the value of this is `0`, print  a newline character (`\n`), otherwise print a tab character (`\t`)]

My main question is: **How to print 5 integers per line ?**

This is the code i have tried

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    int x = 0;
    while ( x <= 20 ) 
    {
        printf("%d", x);
        ++x;
    }
}
```

Comment: The hint that you quoted answers your question.  Did you try it?

Comment: I would solve this by using the calculation x % 5. When the value of this is 0, print a newline character, otherwise print a tab character.

Comment: The statement says *Print the integers from **1** ...* so why are you starting printing from 0 ?

Comment: What is the problem? Don't you know how to print a newline, or don't you know how to use an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

> Print the integers from 1 to 20 using a while loop and the counter variable x.

but your code print the integers from **0** to 20, replace `int x = 0;` by `int x = 1;`

> Use the calculation `x % 5`. When the value of this is 0, print a newline character, otherwise print a tab character.

in C that directly means

```
putchar((x%5) ? '\t' : '\n');
```

or doing in the `printf`

```
printf("%d%c", x, (x%5) ? '\t' : '\n');
```

so finally your code can be:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int x = 1;
  
  while ( x <= 20 ) {
    printf("%d%c", x, (x%5) ? '\t' : '\n');
    ++x;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

% is the modulo operation. a % b integer divide a by b and return the remainder. Thus 3 % 5 -> 3 and 7 % 5 -> 2.

You have the variable x which should go from 0 to 19. If you divide x by 5, the reminder will be a number in the range 0 to 4.

For x = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ...,
x % 5 = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1,...

As you can see, the remainder repeats the numbers from 0 to 4. These are 5 numbers.

So the trick is to print a new line only when x % 5 equals 4.

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 20) {
    printf("%d ", x+1);
    if (x % 5 == 4)
        printf("\n");
    x++;
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks for the feedback. I didn't understand the modulo operator.